# Title tag not overriding after using meta tag module

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I have created a content type for uploading user details. I have changed the title as **UPLOAD PAGE** using [`drupal_set_title`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjo_pbnwbfHAhVQC44KHVjbCjA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fdrupal_set_title&ei=M7TVVaiZGtCWuATYtquAAw&usg=AFQjCNFPzYkNDl5D96uGiUzauLL5jdtqJw&sig2=OFsviA86CGQKhc7Ea_tFbg). I have installed [Meta Tag](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjQ25bZwbfHAhURCY4KHTTKBo4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fmetatag&ei=FrTVVdD4A5GSuAS0lJvwCA&usg=AFQjCNFYBpmiQsOsP3G2t0Xqz7G8mgbb2A&sig2=W7JZJqUuHayCdJZFzGGKHQ) module, now page title remains same but title tag i.e. (title displayed in browser tab) are different. Please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [theme_preprocess_html](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjF-5r9hLrHAhXOvo4KHarEC_Y&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Ffunction%2Ftemplate_preprocess_html%2F7&ei=EgfXVcWqEc79ugSqia-wDw&usg=AFQjCNHU9wQPHMmbLJm0ZtPmu9U_Eno8kA&sig2=AlVHYjswj-OVuxi_AC2kIg) and modify the title using variable `header_title`

Sample code:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['head_title'] = 'TITLE';
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vamsi - $vars['head_title'] did the trick for me after lots of frustrating experiences trying different module/UI and code based methods. Here's how I ended up using this to override a particular view one page at a time:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

  // customize <title> tag for a complex view with url structure /people/%
  if (arg(0)=='people'):
    switch (arg(1)) {
      case 'faculty':
        $vars['head_title'] = 'People - Faculty - My School';
        break;
      case 'graduate-students':
        $vars['head_title'] = 'People - Graduate Students - My School';
        break;
      case 'alumni':
        $vars['head_title'] = 'People - Alumni - My School';
        break;
    }
  endif;

}
```